# How to assign jquery array to an asp.net hidden field

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, listbox

I am getting all selected values in a listbox through jquery. In my listbox, I have done multiselect property also. I am not able to retrieve all the values that I selected in listbox to the hiddenfield. Only the last selected item is retrieving.How to get all values in hiddenfield using jquery? Please help. Code is given below.

```
 $("#button1").click(function () {
                $("#ctl00_BodyContentPlaceHolder_ListBox1 > option:selected").each(function(){
               //var selectedText = $('#ctl00_BodyContentPlaceHolder_ListBox1 option:selected').text();
                //alert(selectedText); 

            $(this).remove().appendTo("#ctl00_BodyContentPlaceHolder_ListBox2");

              var itemArray = []; 
              var arr = new Array();
                $('#ctl00_BodyContentPlaceHolder_ListBox2 :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
                itemArray[i] = $(selected).text(); 

                $('#ctl00_BodyContentPlaceHolder_hdnListItems').val(itemArray[i]);
                alert(itemArray[i]);
                });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you can save only the last value since you are appending the selected list item vlaue to the hidden field in the foreach loop..

corrected functionality is posted below.

```
  $("#button1").click(function() {
    var itemArray = [];

        $("#ctl00_BodyContentPlaceHolder_ListBox1 > option:selected").each(function() {

            $(this).remove().appendTo("#ctl00_BodyContentPlaceHolder_ListBox2");

            var arr = new Array();
            $('#ctl00_BodyContentPlaceHolder_ListBox2 :selected').each(function(i, selected) {
                itemArray.push($(selected).text());
            });
        });
        $('#ctl00_BodyContentPlaceHolder_hdnListItems').val(itemArray);
    });
```

check and let me know the outcome.

Comment: Just now I have done it with another push method. Thanks Vinay.. :)

Answer (score 0):

i think its because you set the last value here

```
$('#ctl00_BodyContentPlaceHolder_hdnListItems').val(itemArray[i]);
```

after the last each loop `itemArray[i]` is the last item

Comment: Ya..I know that its wrong. But how to append each value in the array so that I can get all values in hidden field...

Comment: you can add another array variable and push all the selected values using `.push()` . will those selected values besend to ajax or another purpose?

Comment: Ya, I have done with another array and got the result. Thanks Roullie